# db4o - data partitioning

Tags: db4o

Is it possible to partition data within db4o?

I didn't find much in regards to it being supported on their site directly.  I'd like to keep data around, but migrate it to a different area if it isn't accessed as often.  If there is less data to go through, it should speed up queries.

Is there any way to do this outside of db4o if it isn't supported?

Thanks,

Walter

Comment: What do you have in mind? Having BLOBs outside the db? Or part of the object-graph outside the database and transparently load that stuff when accessed?

Comment: See my comment below, I basically want to archive information.  If the main database my application uses is small, it should be quick(er) than with a large database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just use more than one DB4O database (so you have separate database files) for this?

Comment: Yeah, that is the route I was starting to go, but I will have much more work to do ...  For instance, I wanted to archive old logs, I track HTTP requests, but after a certain point, it isn't really useful any more.  I'd still like to keep it around so that if I want, I can further analyze the data for trends.  What I would have to do is selectively move those objects and any linked ones to that other database (file) which seems to me like it would be a tedious task to get right.

Comment: If you have complex relationships to other objects then I guess it will always be a hard problem. Another way would be to give your archivable classes a simple state field that can be marked as 'archived' and efficiently excluded from searches.

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported in the db4o core but you can use db4o dRS to sync objects between db4o instances (you could use dRS to migrate your object to the "old" store)

http://developer.db4o.com/Solutions/ReplicationServices.aspx

Best!

German

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I came across that in my search.  My first thought is that that would make 2 copies, but perhaps I can use it to make a copy, and then delete the original.

Answer (score 0):

Well thats not an easy task and there's no 'ready-to-go'-solution for this right now.

I guess there are different approaches:

- As you and German already discussed: You could use DRS to replicate everything to second db4o database. And then later on delete the original on the master-database. DRS doesn't replicate deletes by default, so that should work.
- Maybe you could serialize the old data to some other datastore. Then you add a special type which is handled by special [typetranslator](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.0/java/reference/Content/advanced_topics/type_handling/translators.htm). That type represents a 'gateway' to the serialized archive data. When you load that type the translator loads the serialized data from the alternative datastore.

All these solution suffer from some difficulties. They introduce bounderies which you need to cross. That makes the solution a lot more complex =(

Much better would be if the performance degradation can be kept in acceptable range. Then you don't have to do all this. Or consider a database which can handle that amount of data easily.